# How to add more Items to PivotItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on w8 phone application and I have a problem with the fact that I can not have in one PivotItem 2 listboxes.

```
  <phone:PivotItem Header="first" Margin="27,32,296,389">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->


            <ListBox Width="153" FontSize="25" Name="lbi1" Margin="0,0,-13,-78" SelectionChanged="Action1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ListBoxItem Content="1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="4"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="5"/>
            </ListBox>


            <ListBox Width="153" FontSize="25" Name="lbi2" Margin="0,0,-13,-78" SelectionChanged="Action2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ListBoxItem Content="item1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="item2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="item3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="item4"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="item5"/>
            </ListBox>             


        </phone:PivotItem>
```

This is OK, but when I add this second listBox Code I got error:"Content" can only be set once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Grid** or **StackPanel** to the **PivotItem**.

```
        <phone:PivotItem Header="first"
                         Margin="27,32,296,389">
            <Grid>
                <!-- ListBoxes -->
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```